# How to do the prediction after multiple imputation with MICE package

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, prediction, imputation

As part of my analysis, I have to do the prediction but mice doesn't have the tool to do so!
Meaning that using "with" and then "pool" doesn't work!

```
X1<-c(1,1,1,0,0,NA)
X2<c(0,NA,1,NA,NA,0)
X3<-c(1,0,1,1,NA,0)
X4<- c(1,0,1,0,1,1)
data<-data.frame(X1,X2,X3,X4)

p<- glm(X3~X1+X2, family= "binomial", data=subset(data, X4==1))
pre<- predict(p, newdata=data, type="response")
```

Does anyone have any solution? In my case, I have 20 imputed datasets, I tried to do the analysis on each of them separately and then take the mean of the estimates I want but that just does not seem right.

**P.S:**
Question got edited after Steffens answer to make it a bit clear.

Comment: Are you trying to make predictions for observations with missing covariate values, or just for a certain newdata that has fully observed values?

Comment: Your example doesn't have missing values ...

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessenI just edited the question. I want to run the logistic regression on a subset of data (including all the covariates) and then do the prediction for the whole dataset

Comment: Thinking about your comment on Steffen's answer, it seems to make more sense to perform the entire analysis on each imputed dataset and then pool those results, rather than pool the prediction model and then use a single prediction for each observation in the last step of the analysis. What do you think about that?

Comment: Yes, @DavidLukeThiessen makes a good point. If you perform your causal inference on each of the m imputed datasets separately, you are afterwards able to give some meaningful insights how much uncertainty is introduced due to imputation. I don't have too much knowledge about causal inference, but in general you can always state something like std in results was ... min, max for different imputed datasets was ... mean was ... But I there are also several papers out there about multiple imputation for causal inference. Probably they have more advanced ideas about pooling. Certainly worth a look.

Comment: Thank you both for the helpful insights @DavidLukeThiessen ... I ended up with doing the exact thing and the paper that Steffen suggested, I am going to use for the mean, SD and CI, however, it is frustrating if I want to increase the number of datasets that is why I was hoping for a better solution...

Comment: Thank you both for the helpful insights @SteffenMoritz ... I ended up with doing the exact thing and the paper that you suggested, I am going to use for the mean, SD and CI, however, it is frustrating if I want to increase the number of datasets that is why I was hoping for a better solution...

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems incomplete at the moment ... where do you use mice and where are the missing data?

I am assuming you planned something like this:

```
library("mice")
X1 <- c(1,NA,1,0,1,0)
X2 <- c(0,1,1,NA,0,0)
data1 <-data.frame(X1,X2)

imp <- mice(data1)

fit <- with(imp, glm(X1~X2, family = binomial))
summary(pool(fit))
```

This gives you the parameter estimates of the pooled model. If you are interested in them...

Creating predictions is the net step, but there are actually different ways how to approach this (from a scientific perspective). Probably also depends a little on what you are trying to archive (which you did not mention yet)

Here is an interesting paper ["Obtaining Predictions from Models Fit to Multiply Imputed Data"](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0049124115610345) on this issue.

Stef van Buuren (the mice author) also has some suggestions with implementation code here: https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/82

Comment: Thank you Steffen, I just edited the question to be more detailed. My whole analysis (which is causal inference) relies highly on the prediction part because then the predicted values will become a version of the propensity scores so this is so important for me to reach. On the statistical side, I am not very familiar with the concepts, I however read what Van Buuren suggested and even tried it but it ended up with some errors (I guess me being not familiar with the programming could also be a reason)