# How do I utilize imputed data, with categorical levels, in a prediction in R?

Tags: r, prediction, imputation

I'll illustrate my problem with the `iris` data set in R. My objective here is to create 5 imputed data sets, fit a regression to each imputed data set, then pool together the results of these regressions into one final model. This is the preferred order of operations for a proper execution of multiple imputation.

```
library(mice)

df <- iris
# Inject some missingness into the data:
df$Sepal.Width[c(20,40,70,121)] <- NA
df$Species[c(15,80,99,136)] <- NA
# Perform the standard steps of multiple imputation with MICE:
imputed_data <- mice(df, method = c(rep("pmm", 5)), m = 5, maxit = 5)
model <- with(imputed_data, lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species))
pooled_model <- pool(model)
```

This leaves me with this `pooled_model` object which I am hoping to use as a fitted model in the `predict` command. However, that does not work. When I run:

```
predict(pooled_model, newdata = iris)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('mipo', 'data.frame')"
```

Disregard the reasoning why I am using the original `iris` data set in my newly fitted model; I simply want to be able to fit this data, or a subset of it, onto the model I created with my imputation.

I specifically chose a data set with multiple levels of a categorical variable to highlight my problem. I thought about using some matrix multiplication with which I could do this manually, but the presence of a categorical variable makes that tough. In my actual data set, I have over a hundred variables, many of which have multiple categorical levels. I say this because I realize one possible solution would be to re-code my categorical variables into dummy variables, and then I can apply some matrix multiplication to get my answer. But that would be an EXTREME amount of work for me. If there's a way I can somehow get a model object I can use in the predict function, that would make my life 100x easier.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues: 1) how to use `stats::predict` with pooled data and 2) what to do about your categorical variables.

Your first issue has [already been documented on the `mice` Github page](https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/82) and it seems like there's been a desire to have a `predict.mira` function for a while. The author of the `mice` package posted some code on how to simulate a `predict.mira`-like function. Unfortunately, it only works with `lm` models, but it seems like that's okay considering your reprex. If you have a Github account, you can comment on that Github issue to demonstrate your interest in the `predict.mira` function.

Your question also has been posted on [StackOverflow before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460923/how-to-do-the-prediction-after-multiple-imputation-with-mice-package); although the answer was never accepted, the SO user suggested this reading by [Miles (2015)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0049124115610345).

For your second question, have you considered leaving out your current `method` argument when using `mice()`? As long as your variables have been classed as factors, then `mice` will default to the `polyreg` method for categorical variables and `pmm` for continuous variables. [You can read more about the method argument here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.15.0/topics/mice#:%7E:text=Built%2Din%20univariate%20imputation%20methods%20are%3A).

```
library(mice)
set.seed(123)

# make missing data
df <- iris
df$Sepal.Width[c(20,40,70,121)] <- NA
df$Species[c(15,80,99,136)] <- NA

# specify method
meth <- mice(df, maxit = 0, printFlag = FALSE)$meth
print(meth)

# this is how you would change your methods, if you wanted
# but pmm and polyreg are defaults
meth["Species"] <- "polr"
meth["Sepal.Width"] <- "midastouch"
print(meth)

# impute
imputed_data <- mice(df, 
                     m = 5,
                     maxit = 5, 
                     method = meth,  # new method
                     printFlag = FALSE)

# make model
model <- with(imputed_data, lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species))
summary(pool(model))

# obtain predictions Q and prediction variance U
predm <- lapply(getfit(model), predict, se.fit = TRUE)
Q <- sapply(predm, `[[`, "fit")
U <- sapply(predm, `[[`, "se.fit")^2
dfcom <- predm[[1]]$df

# pool predictions
pred <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(Q), ncol = 3,
               dimnames = list(NULL, c("fit", "se.fit", "df")))
for(i in 1:nrow(Q)) {
  pi <- pool.scalar(Q[i, ], U[i, ], n = dfcom + 1)
  pred[i, 1] <- pi[["qbar"]]
  pred[i, 2] <- sqrt(pi[["t"]])
  pred[i, 3] <- pi[["df"]]
}

head(pred)
```